# In which episode is the 'rebel song' sung?

Tags: episode-identification, journey-into-space

In the BBC radio drama *Journey Into Space* (written by Charles Chilton), the crew hears a song 'the rebel song' sung by 'conditioned' humans working for the martians. In which episode is it?

It really struck me when I heard it, but now I can't find it!

---

Found a few scenes in which it's heard in the background, but I remember it being sung for a good chunk...

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_into_Space#Music) indicates that it is played in *The World in Peril*, but I do not have the radio program with which to verify this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's episode 11 of *World in Peril*.

At about 11:30 in, the crew are playing with the televiewer, and manage to tune it in to where the song is being sung. There's a minute or so of the song, though half of it has the cast talking over it, but there's a good thirty seconds where it's just the song.

Comment: Thanks! Found it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln8hCCN7Hyo

Comment: Thank you for an excuse to listen to World in Peril again!

Comment: The words are taken from Heinlein's "The Green Hills of Earth".

Comment: Its chorus is also sung at the end of the final episode.